# How to load collada scene (using three.js)?

Tags: webgl, three.js, collada

I've just started using three.js and am trying to load a scene from *.dae file. And by scene I mean a model (some building), a couple of lights a camera (I want to be able to position it in 3dsmax rather than manually in code).

I found a couple of example codes to load collada files using three.js on the net but none of them showed how to load a camera and lights from *.dae file. I've tried a couple of variants of code to do that but none of it worked and it's so bad I won't even post it here. :P So if anyone could show me how to do that or provided a link to tutorial/code, or at least gave me some guidelines, I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collada loader in three.js doesn't support the lights (and camera) feature.

Comment: Are there any collada loaders that include that?

Comment: not that I know of. but the colladaLoader is opensource so feel free to edit it